# Convert Aggregated field into Non-Aggregated field in Tableau

Tags: aggregate, tableau-api

I have a dataset that sometimes comes with a field (LTV) using number like 83.5 to represent 83.5%, and sometimes with numbers like 0.835.

To avoid that issue, I want to create a calculated field that divides the original rows by 100 in case the average of the field is more than 3, and leaves it without changes in the other case.

The formula that I use to do that is:

**IF AVG([LTV])<3 THEN [LTV] ELSE [LTV]/100 END**

In order to avoid the error in comparison between aggregated and non-aggregated fields, I changed it to:

**IF {AVG([LTV])<3} THEN [LTV] ELSE [LTV]/100 END**

The problem is that Tableau is giving me an aggregated field as a result. What I want is to compare every single row to the average of the whole column in order to make every decision. How can I do that?

I already tried to create a new column that contains the resulting average of the whole column repeated in each row, but I don't know how. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check for the decimal location instead of the amount. This way there is no aggregation.

Try this:

```
if find(str([Ltv]),"0")=1 then [Ltv] else [Ltv]/100 end
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach, but it won't work for records that are <10%, since the decimal point would be in the second position: 5.0 or 0.05; and I can't use the string "0." because I have records that are >100%.

Comment: Is the first digit always zero for values that are already a percentage? Like 0.05 or 0.60? If so, you could check the first digit value.

Comment: Not always, the percentage sometimes is higher than 100%, so the number might start with "1" or even "2", and sometimes could be less than 1%, so it could confuse 0.9% with 90%.

Comment: Can you upload sample data?

Comment: In fact, I cannot. But is really easy to replicate: there are 14,000 rows and each one has a, let say, random number between 0.5% and 250%. That dataset, when the client uploads it, sometimes has the "5" representation of "5%" and other times has the "0.05" representation of "5%".

Comment: I meant the instances where you don't have to divide by 100, should always start with a zero according to your example. you could check for that, updated my answer.

Comment: As I indicated in my 2nd comment, the percentage could be higher than 100% or less than 1%, so the fact that the string starts with a zero or not does not gives any clue, sadly.